# How to create a PreferenceScreen in a PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

Consider the following activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PreferenceScreen screen =
                getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
    }
}
```

Android Studio shows a warning for the call to `getPreferenceManager()`:

> 'getPreferenceManager()' is deprecated
>
> This inspection reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope.

However, it does not describe what corrective action I should take to avoid the warning. I can't find any alternative for obtaining a reference to the `PreferenceManager` and I see no other way to create a `PreferenceScreen`.

My goal is to programatically populate the `PreferenceActivity` with preferences and their default values since these are generated at runtime and cannot be included in `xml/preferences.xml`.

Comment: Settings not use PreferenceFragment to represent a PreferenceScreen. You can follow [the tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `getPreferenceManager()` is deprecated in `SettingsActivity`, it is not deprecated in `PreferenceFragment`. Therefore, the correct way to create a `PreferenceScreen` is as follows:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            PreferenceScreen screen =
                    getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(getActivity());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```